# How to get all node Ids from VIS.js network

Tags: angular2-services, vis.js, vis.js-network

I want to retrieve ids of all the nodes of already rendered vis.js network.
How can I do that?

```
// I want to do something similar to this.
nodeIdArray:String[]= this.network.getAllNodeIds()
```

Any pointer for this is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution to this:

```
this.nodes = new DataSet(data.nodes)//Get the nodes
this.nodes.getIds() //This gives the string array of the node Id's
```

Comment: oh wow, never would have thought about checking docs of DataSet for this :)